# AngularJS validation for ng-repeat form items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am looking for some guidance.

Here is some code I have:

```
<div ng-repeat="q in questions">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><span ng-bind="q.questionText"></span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <answer-field question="q"></answer-field>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`answer-field` is a directive, and essentially depending on what `q` is a certain type of form field will be displayed like a `select` box or an `input text` box, etc.

For example, the select box might be:

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <select class='form-control' ng-model='question.answer' ng-options='item for item in question.choices' required>
        <option value=''>Select an option...</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And the text field might be:

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <input class='form-control' type='text' ng-model='question.answer' required />
</div>
```

As you can see, I have added `required` and this does technically work. The browser will show an error saying I need to fill out that field if I try to submit.

What I would like though is something a little more aesthetically pleasing. Bootstrap has `has-error` for example. It would be nice if instead of the default browser "fill out this field" message if I could make the `form-group` display `has-error` - and ideally display somewhere a list of the items that do indeed have an error.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

[Angular has `novalidate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms). It suppresses the native HTML validation, allowing you to put in your own. As for how to show custom errors, it's also in that page.

Comment: If I understand that correctly, `ng-invalid` would be applied to invalid form fields? If that is right, how can I make that display `has-error` on the form-group?

Answer (score 0):

I often like to display custom error messages as follows:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group has-error">
    <p class="help-block" ng-show="form.password.$error.required && submitted">
       Please enter password.
    </p>
  </div>
```

or you can use `ng-class` to append the `has-error` class to the first `div` based on the expression

Comment: I am using ng-repeat though - so my input fields don't have `name` attributes. I would love to display it in the way you have described, but I just don't know how to do the equivalent of `ng-show="form.password.$error.required && submitted"` given I don't have name's like password on each of my form fields.